# How to load part of section directly from Akamai to AWS S3 without requesting the origin server?

Tags: amazon-s3, akamai

I have one website, which is deployed on AWS instance and we have Akamai CDN. We are storing data in S3. We have few modules which do not require any processing from the web server and that can be directly served because those are pure static files say (RSS). Is there any way to load some links directly from Akamai to S3 without requesting the origin server?

For example, `http://www.example.com/rss/1000.rss`, can this `/rss/*` directly be configured in Akamai luna to load it from relevant S3 URL?

We tried sitefailover but it does not support the non property URLs Host names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new rule in Property Manager.

[image: new rule]

Add a match criteria, for `/rss/*`.

[image]

Add an *Origin Server* behavior.

[image]

Notes:

- Set the *Forward Host Header* to *Origin Hostname*.
- Set the *Origin Server Hostname* to a hostname that maps to your S3 bucket (replace `yourbucket`).
- Make sure the files in the S3 bucket are publicly readable (`public-read` ACL).

Comment: tried according to your configuration but it is throwing reference error `An error occurred while processing your request. Reference #30.153f3217.1542364921.1f29a6 `